# Flight cancellation luggage

Tags: luggage, cancellations, american-airlines, iberia

I booked a ticket from Amsterdam to Philadelphia. This was a direct flight from American Airlines. This ticket got cancelled today and rebooked by American Airlines. I'm traveling one day later (tomorrow, December 18th) from Amsterdam to Madrid with Iberia airlines and then from Madrid to Philadelphia with American Airlines.

I checked in online at Iberia and I noticed that it said that my ticket contains 1 carry on and 0 checked in baggage, which is strange because at American Airlines I always get 1 checked in luggage for free.

[image]

I contacted American Airlines where I got a poorly English speaking person on the phone. I told her about my situation and she was real short saying something like "yeah that will be solved at the airport" which was basically all the info she could give me.

I'm sort of afraid that I arrive at the airport tomorrow and they either don't have space for luggage or I have to pay extra (which isn't a real big deal) but as you expect, I'm sort of nervous about this. What do I do and how do I handle this situation?

Also, my reservation at American Airlines says the following at my Madrid->Philadelphia trip: `Baggage: CUST`. What does this mean and does that have any influence on my trip from Amsterdam to madrid?

**Edit for whoever cares**

I made it safely to the USA without any problems. The baggage was no problem at all, I didn't even need to ask for anything. Thanks for everybodies help :)

[image]

Comment: @pnuts it got cancelled by American Airlines because of either the weather or a defect aircraft (this wasn't clear to me). AA also rebooked the flight for me. I did an edit in my post by the way.

Comment: @pnuts is there a chance they will say "sorry we don't have space for your luggage"?

Comment: @pnuts Thanks for your info! That makes me a little less nervous (I haven't traveled much in my life yet). do you know what the `Baggage: CUST` part means?

Comment: @pnuts it's the weather, with a cold front rolling through, and freezing rain icing runways. AA must have rescheduled OP in anticipation.

Comment: @Dorothy I thought that too at first but all international flights are fine except some flights from within the U.S.A. (http://www.phl.org/Pages/Flight-Information.aspx) so I wonder if that's the reason! The lady also said something about a defect plane so that might just be the only reason. I'm not sure.

Comment: It's just as well, as it seems to be affecting airports throughout the Northeast. I'm on the US East Coast, five hours behind your time zone, and Philly has been closed, one runway has re-opened, Dulles is closed; both with iced runways. The knock on would have been an issue for your mid-afternoon arrival. Take your compensation money and have a great time here.

Comment: @Dorothy Thank you :) hope my flight won't get cancelled again when I'm in Spain, but as far as I know tomorrow it will be 60f tomorrow so that's promising.

Comment: You should be fine; there's a warm front right behind the cold, very much warmer tomorrow (and rain) but a big drop in temp on Monday, so bring your cold weather gear.

Comment: American includes 1 checked bag in transatlantic fares.  Just explain to the Agent that you originally booked the ticket on American and they should take the bag no charge.  They can see the flight change so you don't really need to show them anything.  Don't worry about space, they will offload cargo before passenger baggage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about lack of space for your checked bags. It is possible that they will try to make you pay, at which point you can explain the situation and request that they waive the charges. If they refuse, you can pay and take the issue up with American's customer service (or lack thereof) after the flight.

"Baggage: CUST" is, in a rather confusing way, trying to tell you at which baggage claim in Philadelphia your luggage it scheduled to arrive. In this case, your bags will, of course, go to the Customs area, as this is an international flight. This space might display a baggage claim number for customers traveling on domestic flights, but it's always a good idea to check the monitors when you arrive to find the correct baggage carousel.